# Material-ui clear TextField Select using React Refs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 Textfields, one is simple Textfield and the other one is a Select. When I use refs on them, setting the value to blank using refs clears the Textfield but doesn't clears the Select.

```
class A extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     this.nameRef = React.createRef()
     this.jobRef = React.createRef()
   }

   clear = () => {
        this.nameRef.current.value = ''
        this.jobRef.current.value= '' // also tried setting -1
   }

   return <> 
      <TextField 
          inputRef={this.nameRef}          
      />
      <TextField 
        inputRef={this.jobRef}   
        select={true}
       
     >
       {
         [{key: 0, value: 'Random'}].map(item=><MenuItem key={item.key}>{item.value}</MenuItem>)
       }
     </TextField>
     <button onClick={this.clear}>Clear</button>
   </>
}
```

Comment: `React.createRef()` should be inside constructor instead

Comment: It doesn't works when refs are created within constructor. Refs are working fine, but its the clearing issue not working on Textfield when select prop is used.

Comment: I don't think Refs appropriate to update the value. You need to use controller components to handle form data. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: I am using refs to control Filters on a page, using state for such a trivial task seems too much unecessary work.

Comment: Your code [works](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fzh8e?file=/demo.tsx). Please fork the codesandbox and reproduce the bug so others can help you.